# Anime where girl has a powerful revolver that hurts her to shoot

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm looking for this anime where this girl had like this over-powered revolver and it hurts her to shoot it. In one scene she runs out of bullets and has one as a necklace and she shoots it and kills the bad guy or monster. I can't remember what it's called.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Just noting for future queries, we had a similar question involving a make with a bullet used from a necklace on their neck at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178097/possible-anime-from-mtv-circa-2000-2002-about-a-cop-who-carried-a-special-bullet?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 4):

[GoShogun: The Time Étranger.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoShogun#The_Time_%C3%89tranger)

You can see the scene below. The main character is hurt by the recoil from her handgun and is out of bullets. She uses the one on her necklace.

Comment: Great find. I've taken the liberty of adding a small description and changed the video link. If you go into "share link" in youtube, you can set a timecode.

Answer (score 2):

[Gunslinger Girl](https://myanimelist.net/anime/134/Gunslinger_Girl) (2003) by Madhouse Studios

[image: Gunslinger Girl]

Originally Gunslinger Girl was a manga by Yu Aida. It premiered on May 21, 2002, in the monthly shōnen manga magazine Dengeki Daioh.

Comment: Can you explain why this property is a match to the question asked?